# problem with gcov, cannot run

Tags: 12.04, programming, gcc

So i'm trying to optimize a file called `linpack.c`. I have to use `gcov` to find the 10 most executed lines. I've been given these compiler options:

```
-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O2
```

So i ran this

```
$ gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O2 linpack.c
```

the output was `linpack, linpack.gcno`.

Now when I try to run `gcov linpack.c` in order to generate `linpack.c.gcov` I get an error:

```
linpack.gcda, cannot open data file.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This should be straightforward but I have been struggling for more than an hour now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `linpack.gcda` file should get created when you execute the program that you compiled with the profile flags. Since you didn't supply an output file name (using the `-o` option) on the gcc command line, you will need to execute it as `a.out`. For example:

```
$ gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O2 hello.c
$ ls hello.*
hello.c  hello.gcno
$ 
$ ./a.out 
Hello world!
$ ls hello.*
hello.c  hello.gcda  hello.gcno
$
```